# How does MapReduce Job work on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, word-count

So I'm new to the whole Big Data movement, and Hadoop specifically.  I am wondering if a file in HDFS is already split up, how does a MapReduce job execute if the file is already split up?  So for instance, the simple word count MapReduce job on a text file.  My understanding is that in HDFS the file will be divided up and spread over the data nodes.  Does the word count job work on the already split up file, or does it do it's own split of the file?  As a mapreduce programmer should one not worry about how the file gets split up?

As a follow-up, when HDFS does do it's split of a file, does it filter and split up using any defined rules?  So for instance, it's a phone book will the HDFS know to split up blocks by aphabetical order, like all A's in one block all B's in another and so forth?

Sorry for the amount of questions in this post and if they are way off base.  Just wanted some clarification as I go through some tutorials online  :)  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you need not worry about splitting the files manually. It splits by size(64 MB by default). Say WordCount example on a file of size 70MB with default block size. Simple - you get 2 mappers working on both the splits... and your reducer collates the result.

On splitting by content, A-B-C ... AFAIK, it all depends on the block size, not on the characters. Is there any advantage for you to split the files based on the characters?

Comment: So if the file is already in HDFS, will WordCount still need to split up the file?

And to your question, an advantage could be that doing a query/look-up would be more efficient.  So if I want to search for name, "Jack" it will go to the block where the J's reside?  But that might not be what hadoop is about since it's more about un-organized data.

Comment: On the question " will WordCount still need to split up the file", answer is NO. The wordcount maps will be allotted the their portion of file blocks to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

- The splitiing is done based on the size of the input file, if its larger than 64MB then the file will be splitted into blocks, so at the end HDFS stores these blocks into datanodes. Developer need not worry about how the splitting is done. Its the framework which takes care of this.
- Hadoop does not know where the particular alphabet starts in a file so by default the splitting is done based on the input file size and not the content.

Answer (score 0):

> how does a MapReduce job execute if the file is already split up?

In HDFS the files are stored in blocks (default block size is 64MB, you can set it via `dfs.block.size` property). If the file is larger than the block size, then the file is split into chunks that are equal to or less than the block size. So, if the input file for the mapreduce job is larger than the block size, then it is split. Otherwise it is not. And yes, the job executes on all the files that are given as input (whether the framework splits the file or you do that manually)

> Does the word count job work on the already split up file, or does it
>   do it's own split of the file?

After a file has been pushed onto HDFS, it breaks the file physically into blocks and copies them to the datanodes. While running a mapreduce job, the `InputFormat` of the job computes input splits for the file. Input splits are logical. A map task is run for every input split.

So, even if there are more than one parts of a file (whether you split it manually or HDFS chunked it), after `InputFormat` computes the input splits, the job runs on all parts of the file.

> As a mapreduce programmer should one not worry about how the file gets
>   split up?

Usually, a programmer doesn't need to worry about it. However, it is always good to know how HDFS splits the files and problems/advantages associated with it. And obviously, if you want to change the customize the `InputFormat` to your needs then you need to know.

> when HDFS does do it's split of a file, does it filter and split up using any defined rules?

HDFS splits file if it exceeds the block size, no other rule. If you want an input split based on any defined rule (like the one you mentioned) then you have to override the defaults.

PS: I think you are confused between HDFS blocks and input splits.

Comment: Thank you...this helps clarify.  So to sum, hdfs blocks are where the file is physically stored, the input splits are logical in the sense that the mapreduce will receive the input file and divide the file/work and not worry about where they are physically stored.

Comment: yes. a new map task is spawned for every input split.